# Avoiding square and cubic root of complex number

Tags: complex, algebra

I want to simplify following expression to avoid calculation of square and cubic root of complex numbers:

$ \sqrt[3]{R + \sqrt{Q^3 + R^2)}} + \sqrt[3]{R - \sqrt{Q^3 + R^2})}$

where $ Q, R \in  \mathbb{R}$.

I know that the result is a real number.

Comment: Sorry where is the the right half side of this equation?

Comment: I'm sorry, it's an expression not an equation, I fixed it.

Comment: What is the "solution of an expression" then?  I only know about solutions of equations.

Comment: simpified form of this expression where you don't need to calculate square and cubic root of complex number

Comment: What do you mean by "I know that the solution is a real number."?  Put 1 for both Q and R and the result has a non-zero imaginary part.   Finally, can you explain why you believe that there is a "simpler" form and what exact form you are looking for?

Comment: The solution is a real number for any $Q, R \in \mathbb{R}$. And simpler form is a form without cubic root of $\sqrt{Q^3 + R^2}$.

Comment: I really don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: `Expand[(r - Sqrt[q^3 + r^2])^(3/2) + (r + Sqrt[q^3 + r^2])^(3/2)]` yields `r Sqrt[r - Sqrt[q^3 + r^2]] - 
 Sqrt[q^3 + r^2] Sqrt[r - Sqrt[q^3 + r^2]] + 
 r Sqrt[r + Sqrt[q^3 + r^2]] + 
 Sqrt[q^3 + r^2] Sqrt[r + Sqrt[q^3 + r^2]]`

Comment: @Feyre the point is that the exponential of the two expressions is (1/3), not (3/2).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue it raises is not really a Mathematica issue but a matter of the OP not having grasped the mathematics involved.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Surd[..., 2]` instead of `Sqrt`, and `CubeRoot` (or `Surd[..., 3]`) instead of `^(1/3)`:

```
expr = CubeRoot[(r - Surd[q^3 + r^2, 2])] + CubeRoot[(r + Surd[q^3 + r^2, 2])]
```

[image]

```
expr /. {r -> 1, q -> 1}
```

[image]

```
N @ %
```

> 0.596072

---

Note that the shape of the square root symbol is different for `Sqrt` and `Surd`:

```
Sqrt[a + b]
Surd[a + b, 2]
```

[image]

to indicate graphically the differences between the two functions.

**NOTE:** Because there's a square root of `q^3 + r^2` in `expr`, not all real `r, q` will lead to real `expr`. E.g.,

```
expr /. {r -> 1, q -> -2}
```

> Indeterminate

Values of `r` and `q` for which `Surd[q^3 + r^2, 2]` are real:

```
RegionPlot[q^3 + r^2 >= 0, {r, -5, 5}, {q, -5, 5}, FrameLabel -> {"r", "q"}]
```

[image]

that is

```
Reduce[q^3 + r^2 >= 0, {q, r}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
expr1 = (r + Sqrt[q^3 + r^2])^(1/3) +
   (r - Sqrt[q^3 + r^2])^(1/3);

expr1 /. {r -> 4., q -> 4.}

(*  3.19977 + 1.47536 I  *)

plt1 = Plot3D[expr1 , {r, -5, 5}, {q, -5, 5},
  PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}, Automatic},
  PlotPoints -> 75,
  MaxRecursion -> 4,
  AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]

If you use [`Surd`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Surd.html) to get the real-valued third root,

```
expr2 = Surd[r + Sqrt[q^3 + r^2], 3] +
   Surd[r - Sqrt[q^3 + r^2], 3];

plt2 = Plot3D[expr2, {r, -5, 5}, {q, -5, 5},
   PlotPoints -> 75,
   MaxRecursion -> 4,
   AxesLabel -> Automatic] // Quiet
```

[image]

Using [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) to combine the two functions

```
expr3 = Piecewise[{{expr2, q^3 + r^2 >= 0}}, expr1];

Plot3D[expr3, {r, -5, 5}, {q, -5, 5},
  PlotPoints -> 75,
  MaxRecursion -> 5,
  AxesLabel -> Automatic] // Quiet
```

[image]

Using [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html) to combine `plt1` and `plt2`

```
Show[plt1, plt2,
 PlotPoints -> 75,
 MaxRecursion -> 5,
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]